application keep referring to kind cluster when it doesn't exit
I am installing a kubernetes supported application testkube  on my local. 
What I did

Had minikube running
Installed testkube app by choco install. and found that testkube is not working.Someone suggested to try on kind instaead of minikube
Uninstalled testkube by using choco uninstall
Installed 'kind' & switched context . install the testkube again using choco install. testkube did not work
I deleted the kind cluster When I finally figured out the issue. the issue was admin user was installing testkube and minikube/kind was installed using non-admin user

So as to test my theory I deleted minikube and reinstalled it using admin user
now only minikube context is available in kubectl config get-contexts and I explicitly set the context as minikube kubectl config set-context minikube
Problem
installed testkube app again and when checking the version for testkube I am getting error . it seems is it still refering to kind cluster.
api server response: '{"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"services \"testkube-api-server\" not found","reason":"NotFound","details":{"name":"testkube-api-server","kind":"services"},"code":404}
Not sure what is missing and how to get it to refer minikube
